# Create folder inside debug or release con console application

Tags: c#-4.0, compilation, console-application, directory

i have a console application in vs2010 (C#) and in the project, i have a Folder added by me (right click on project.. add->folder) and i want that when i compile the application (debug or release), then the folder will be created (if not exists) in the debug or release directory.

Is that possible?

The console application is a daemon that access to a database and send emails with templates allocated in that folder.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve it, like this:
in the csproj:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)EmailTemplates" Condition="!Exists('$(OutDir)EmailTemplates')" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Templates Include="$(ProjectDir)EmailTemplates\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Templates)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)EmailTemplates" />
  </Target>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8):

There's no "automatic" way to get VS to create folders (other than the specified output folder) during a build, but there's two pretty easys ways to accomplish it.

- Use a post-build event, which you set up in the Build Events tab of your project's properties. This is basically a batch file that you run after the build completes, something like this:

  ```
  IF NOT EXIST $(OutDir)MySubFolder MKDIR $(OutDir)MySubFolder
  XCOPY /D $(ProjectDir)MySubFolder\*.tmpl $(OutDir)MySubFolder
  ```
- Use MSBuild's AfterBuild event. This is my preferred method, mostly because it integrates better with our automated build process, but it's a little more involved:

  1. Right-click on your project node and Unload it
  2. Right-click on the unloaded project node and Edit the file
  3. Near the bottom is a commented-out pair of XML nodes. Uncomment the AfterBuild target and replace it with something like this:

     ```
     <Target Name="AfterBuild">
         <MakeDir Directory="$(OutDir)MySubFolder" Condition="!Exists('$(OutDir)MySubFolder')" />

         <CreateItem Include="$(ProjectDir)MySubFolder\*.tmpl">
           <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Templates" />
         </CreateItem>    

         <Copy SourceFiles="@Templates" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)MySubFolder" ContinueOnError="True" />
     </Target>
     ```
  4. Save the changes, close the .csproj file, then right-click and Reload the project.

Comment: Woow! nice! the only thing is that in the Release folder (or Debug) the folder is created but nothing is copied inside and in the relese folder appears a bin directory with release folder inside.