# How to automatically create a folder in the output folder with MSBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am using VS Code and Net Core 1.1.1

I need to create a folder named "Database" inside my output directory at building time. This is the folder where I want the sqlite database to be stored after creation.

I already copy files into the output folder like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Data\\Seed\\Countries.csv">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

How should I modify the .csproj file to automatically create the folder I need in my output direcory?

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849283/create-folder-inside-debug-or-release-con-console-application) old question, I tried to add the following code but the folder is not created.

```
<Target Name="efcore">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)Database" Condition="!Exists('$(OutDir)Database')" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You almost had it. You need to chain your target into the build system by adding "AfterTargets".

```
<Target Name="MakeMyDir" AfterTargets="Build">
   <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)Database" />
</Target>
```